# How to implement undo/redo with programatic change of the textValue of a NSTextView?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, undo-redo

I created a simple demo app with a NSTextView and a button, the provided a NSTextViewDelegate to the textView and added an action:

```
- (IBAction)actionButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSString *oldText = [[[self.textView textStorage] string] copy];
    NSString *newText = @"And... ACTION!";

    [[self.textView undoManager] registerUndoWithTarget:self.textView
                                               selector:@selector(setString:)
                                                 object:oldText];
    [[self.textView undoManager] setActionName:@"ACTION"];

    [self.textView setString:newText];
}
```

Undo/redo works without problems, if I change text by hand. But if I change the text with the action method, undo works as expected, but redo does not work anymore (nothing happens) and the undo manager seems to be scrambled...

OK - to avoid problems with NSTextView I created a model class, bound the NSTextView to it and   moved the undo/redo to the model, but this shows the same behavior as before - what the I'm doing wrong - this should be easy, shouldn't it?

```
#import "GFTextStore.h"

@implementation GFTextStore

@synthesize textVal = textVal_;

-(void)changeText{
    if (!undoMan_) {
        undoMan_ = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] undoManager];   
    }

    NSAttributedString *oldText = [self.textVal copy];
    NSString *tempStr = [[oldText string] stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@",[[NSCalendarDate date]description]];
    NSAttributedString *newText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:tempStr];

    [self setTextVal:newText];


    [undoMan_ registerUndoWithTarget:self
                            selector:@selector(setTextVal:)
                              object:oldText];

    [undoMan_ setActionName:@"ACTION"];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 16):

No need to add the NSUndoManager here, just let the NSTextView do the job.

You just need to make sure you are calling the **higher level methods only** of NSTextView beginning with *insert…* and not setting the text/string of the textView or the textStorage directly:

```
    [self.textView insertText:newString];
```

If you absolutely need to use setString or other lower level methods, then you just need to add the required methods handling the textDidChange delegation: **-shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString** and **-didChangeText** (which is done by the insert... methods btw):

```
if( [self.textView shouldChangeTextInRange:editedRange replacementString:editedString]) {
    // do some fancy stuff here…
    [self.textView.textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:editedRange
                          withAttributedString:myFancyNewString];
    // … and finish the editing with
    [self.textView didChangeText];
}
```

This automatically lets the undoManager of NSTextView kick in. I think the undoManager is preparing an undoGrouping in shouldChangeTextInRange: and invoking the undo in didChangeText:.

Answer (score 5):

`-setString:` is an inherited method from `NSText`. To handle this using `NSTextView` methods only so that undo is handled, just do this:

```
[self.textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, [[self.textView textStorage] length])];
[self.textView insertText:@"And… ACTION!"];
```

Making the text change this way avoids mucking about with the undo manager at all.

Comment: Thank you Rob, but that doesn't resolve my problem. To avoid problems with NSTextView I did some changes and moved the undo/redo to the model - see the edited question...

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want your NSTextView to create a new undo group when user hits the Enter key (Apple Pages behavior). Then you might type this code in your NSTextView subclass:

```
override func shouldChangeTextInRange(affectedCharRange: NSRange, replacementString: String?) -> Bool {
    super.shouldChangeTextInRange(affectedCharRange, replacementString: replacementString)
    guard replacementString != nil else { return true }

    let newLineSet = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
    if let newLineRange = replacementString!.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(newLineSet) {

        // check whether it's a single character (user hit Return key)
        let singleCharRange = (replacementString!.startIndex)! ..< (replacementString!.startIndex.successor())!
        if newLineRange == singleCharRange {
            self.breakUndoCoalescing()
        }
    }

    return true
}
```