# Strange crash in UITextview undo on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, crash-reports, undo

I have been receiving a bunch of crash reports that look a lot like the following with different values for the range. Sometimes the range is not 0-x it could be say 2-x

Application Specific Information:*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception \'NSRangeException\',reason: \'*** -[NSBigMutableString substringWithRange:]: Range {0, 69} out of bounds; string length 0\'

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2e879e83 __exceptionPreprocess + 131
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x38bd66c7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2e879dc5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 112
3   Foundation                          0x2f1a1bd1 -[NSString substringWithRange:] + 120
4   UIKit                               0x311b2815 -[NSTextStorage(UIKitUndoExtensions)     _undoRedoAttributedSubstringFromRange:] + 132
5   UIKit                               0x315d9679 -[_UITextUndoOperationTyping undoRedo] + 296
6   Foundation                          0x2f296453 -[_NSUndoStack popAndInvoke] + 250
7   Foundation                          0x2f2952ef -[NSUndoManager undoNestedGroup] + 454
8   UIKit                               0x3127a147 -[UIApplication alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] + 142
9   UIKit                               0x31216449 -[_UIModalItemsCoordinator _notifyDelegateModalItem:tappedButtonAtIndex:] + 144
10  UIKit                               0x3121638d -[_UIModalItemAlertContentView tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 1000
11  UIKit                               0x3111b0cb -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1078
12  UIKit                               0x311ce863 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 214
13  UIKit                               0x3107e781 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 316
14  UIKit                               0x30ff67bb _afterCACommitHandler + 430
15  CoreFoundation                      0x2e844f69 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
16  CoreFoundation                      0x2e8428f7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 286
17  CoreFoundation                      0x2e842c43 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
18  CoreFoundation                      0x2e7ad471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
19  CoreFoundation                      0x2e7ad253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
20  GraphicsServices                    0x334e72eb GSEventRunModal + 138
21  UIKit                               0x31062845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
22  MyApp                               0x00071f3b main (main.m:18)
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x390cfab7 start + 2
```

Comment: Can you share the code that sets up the range?

Comment: There is no code that sets this up. You can see that there are actually no calls coming from my app specifically. Everything is from the shake-to-undo function of the OS which should be handled OK. I'm interested if anyone else has this problem and if there is a workaround.

Comment: I have just had the same problem when writing text undo works fine, but when i use my autosuggest and pick a value, and the keyboard stays shown and the textfield is empty and I shake my phone and clicks undo, and then it crashes. I just disbled shake to undo for now.

Comment: looks like your text has been changed without letting the text view undo manager about it, undo manager thinks your is of length 69 where are actually it is 0. Use one of the more higher level functions (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11760548/207682)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you set UITextView's text property after user edit it, it seems that you need to call [textView.undoManager removeAllActions] to clear undo history.

Comment: That's good but I wish I could use the undo anyway, even if I manually change the text (for instance adjusting the value to stay within a certain bound of numbers)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262691/how-to-implement-undo-redo-with-programatic-change-of-the-textvalue-of-a-nstextv/8263781#8263781) to *How to implement undo/redo with programatic change of the textValue of a NSTextView?*.